# How to detect the sine wave signal with different frequency using neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, algorithm-request, signal-processing

I'm wondering if there is a way to use a neural network that can detect the noisy sine wave, where the frequency is not constant. In other words, I'm not looking for a solution that would detect the signal of a particular frequency (say 50Hz), but a solution that can detect any sine wave signal in say range (100-1000Hz).

Comment: Probably. Just train it on a bunch of different noisy sine waves and signals that aren't.